# Problems sizing div between header and footer

Tags: html, css

A while back I inherited a page to make some tweaks to, which had been thrown together with a lot of manually positioned and sized elements, resulting in a sloppy looking layout. I made some changes a while back to clean things up (and make it look consistent across browsers, which was the bulk of the request). Here is a [JSfiddle that has more or less the result.](https://jsfiddle.net/skoobydoo/puhwak44/1/)

I've since decided it would be much better to have the page resize itself more or less gracefully, as this page is being used in an environment with various aspect ratios. My goal was to have the lower section a fixed height, with the textarea expanding to fill the space, and then the map consuming the remainder of the vertical space. I've accomplished this before by setting the footer to a % height, and the content to 100% minus that amount, but I'm trying to get a fixed height footer here. I've followed a couple of samples that seem like they should work with no success. [Here's a modified JSfiddle where I'm currently at](https://jsfiddle.net/skoobydoo/g9wu2y7v/2/).

The most relevant level of CSS to what I'm currently working with is as follows (see jsfiddle for full page):

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#page {
    position:   relative;
    width:      100%;
    height:     100%;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
}

#titleBar {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    height: 60px;
    background:lightgray;
}

#mapWrapper {
    background:lightblue;

    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 250px;

    /* need to specify some sort of height to get this to appear*/
    /* would be great if I could say "100% - 60px - 240px" */
    height:200px;
}

#entireBottomBar {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

To be clear, how can I make the map div expand to fill the full vertical height of the page, without covering/going behind the header and/or footer.

Comment: Sorry.... what's the question/problem?

Comment: Do you want to avoid the black background area that appears in the middle of your page when page's browser window is expanded?

Comment: *"I've since decided it would be much better to have the page resize itself more or less gracefully, as this page is being used in an environment with various aspect ratios."* - have you considered using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: The map is not expanding to fill the vertical space. In this example I've specified it to be 200 px tall.

Comment: I've never used bootstrap but I'm looking into it. I'm fairly certain there should be a simple solution to this that's pure CSS/JS. I've done this before with horizontal space with two adjacent divs with some sort of overflow trick, but I had a hard time adapting it to this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this in a couple steps:

1. Wrap the upper two divs in one upperstuffdiv
2. Set upperstuffdiv to size border-box, with a bottom border the size of the footer, and change the box-sizing to border-box (so the 100% height would subtract the space dedicated to the footer)
3. In a similar fashion, within the uperstuffdiv set the mapwrapper to have a top border the size of the header (title)
4. change its box sizing so that size 100% would correct for the upper "border"
5. Changed title div to position:fixed because I couldn't get float or z-index to work the way I expected to render it over the map's upper border.

I'm still interested in hearing alternative approaches or the ins/outs of my methodology.